# Read string from url android studio

Tags: java, android

I want to send country and network by url to my Sql DB and return shortcode to send sms by this Short Code 
I have below Java code :

```
public void send(View view) {
    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.send);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            final String country = tm.getSimCountryIso();
            TelephonyManager NW = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            final String Network = NW.getSimOperatorName();
            try {
                boolean smssc ;
                URL url = new URL("http://93.95.207.35/SMS2App/sc.asp?country=" + country + "&operatorname=" + Network +"");
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
                while ((smssc=in.readLine() !=null));
                StringBuilder SC =new StringBuilder();
                String messageToSend = "Hi";
                getDefault().sendTextMessage(SC, null, messageToSend, null, null);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error in your code. Try this:

```
url = new URL("http://93.95.207.35/SMS2App/sc.asp?country=" + country + "&operatorname=" + Network +"");
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

// open the stream and put it into BufferedReader
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
```

Then this is usually how I read the content:

```
line=in.readLine();
                while (line!= null) {
                    result=result+line;
                    line=in.readLine();
                }
                //System.out.print(result);
                in.close();
```

And result is your string from your url.